# App's body text can flicker when near bottom of screen

Tags: bug, android-app

This video screen grab on YouTube shows what is going on on my device : -link dead because I don't have the youtube account anymore-

Edit: Removed Annoying Mic audio.. Link back up now.

My Android specs: Model z988, Android version 6.0.1, Build number z988V1.4.18, developer options are enabled.

Edit: App version is 1.0.1

Hopefully this isn't too minor to report.

Comment: Well there is no link in the question. And dont you think it is better to add the issue details here?

Comment: This bug happened a while ago, and I have since gotten rid of the youtube account the screen capture was hosted on. The app version 1.0.4 doesn't seem to have this bug anymore. The title really does capture the essence of the bug details. I'd rehost the video, but I don't have it anymore, and I cannot reproduce the bug since it's fixed in 1.0.4 (that I'm using). -- The reason you're probably seeing this post is because I edited the link out to stave future "why is the link down?" comments.

Comment: Oh ok. I see you asked in June. My bad.. If it is fixed I guess you could update that it is fixed in the later version